# How to delete my account from Area51?

Tags: support, area-51, deleted-accounts

I have an account in Area51, which I want to delete.

I want to delete only that account, not other accounts I have in Stack Exchange.

How can I do that? I tried to contact administrator of the network (area51@stackoverflow.com) but have not gotten any response yet.

Comment: @soup you're right, I didn't notice and just used my hammer here to re-establish the dupe status with the new mechanism, i.e. have it as banner and not inside the question body. I can't use it now to reopen, you can try asking in the Tavern, hopefully enough people will see and vote to reopen.

Answer (score 6):

In order to get the account deleted, you should:

- change the username to "delete"
- change the user information given in "About Me" to "Please delete this account"

After you do that, you can send an email to the email address to which you already sent your email. Until you change the user details as I reported, your account will not be deleted. The changes serve to show the request to delete the account has been done from who can access the account for which has been requested the deletion.

Comment: "you can send an email to the email address to which you already sent your email" <- I am sorry, but I send emails to many email addresses, with an overwhelming majority doesn't have anything to do with the SE.

Comment: That was in reply to *I tried to contact administrator of the network (area51@stackoverflow.com)*.