# How do you delete your account at Area 51?

Tags: support, area-51, deleted-accounts

It was quite simple to delete many accounts by clicking on 'help', but I cannot find such a   possibility at Area51.

Can someone tell me how to delete that account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a [frequently asked question over at Meta.Stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account) and has a [specific question about Area51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106839/how-to-delete-my-account-from-area51) accounts (which closed as duplicate of the previous). The process is simple:

1. Change your name to `delete`
2. Change your profile to say `Please delete this account`
3. Go to the [Contact Us](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/contact) page and fill out the form, stating you'd like your account deleted.

That's pretty much it, network-wide.

Comment: _"Go to the Contact Us page and fill out the form.."_ that form doesn't work, it says: this operation can't be performed ...

Comment: Hmm, not sure what to do then. But presumably someone from SE will notice your name and delete it without that (though it may take some time).

Comment: Exactly. The text is a lie. There's a selection for "I need to delete my user profile" but after filling in the form and submitting, it says the operation cannot be performed. A waste of my time.

Comment: @sss4r down voting my post might vent your frustration, but it's not going to help solve your problem, which would be to make a *new* post about the issue.

Comment: Right. I tried changing my vote but told it's locked unless you edit the answer.

Comment: @sss4r : don't worry about the downvote, it's really okay (it's only 2 imaginary internet points)

Comment: Please edit your answer in the slightest, I'll change my vote -- I don't even know why I down-voted it. As you guessed, I was just frustrated, wasn't my clearest thinking.