# Unifying two accounts and deleting accounts which I never use

Tags: support, multiple-accounts

I have different two accounts on mathoverflow.net. One is an old one that is so old I cannot remember how I log in (I don't know the ID and password).

Recently I found math.stackexchange.com and I made an ID, which can be logged in with Google. I created several accounts on several sites. For instance: Area 51, Stack Overflow, and TeX.

Hence I have two IDs on mathoverflow.net. I want to tie them together.

- Hee Kwon Lee reputation 125 silver badge 1 bronze badge 7 (old one)
- Hee Kwon Lee reputation 118 bronze badge 4 (recent one)

I want to place the information from the old one, for instance, question, badges, (except profile information, since I can rewrite) and so on, into the more recent one.

How can I do this?

Furthermore, I have three accounts on Area 51, Stack Overflow and TeX. I do not use them now, since I made the accounts out of curiosity. How can I delete them?

Comment: May I attach suitable tag ? I can not convince tag, feature-request. Thank you for attention.

Comment: @ grgarside Thank you for your nice editting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To merge two accounts, log in to one of them, navigate to the [/contact](https://mathoverflow.net/contact) form and select 'I need to merge user profiles'. Here you can provide a link to the other profile. As the accounts have little reputation, the merge should be automatic (once you confirm ownership). You can find more information on [/help/merging-accounts](https://mathoverflow.net/help/merging-accounts).

To delete accounts which haven't participated, go [/users/edit/current](https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/current) and click Delete Profile.

Comment: Thank you for your answering, but can you give me a tip for deleting account for area 51. I deleted two. But area 51 has different form from two.

Comment: @HKLee http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246865/how-do-you-delete-your-account-at-area-51

Comment: @ Wizard Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Is this answer still current? I tried it and it doesn't work.

Comment: @user What did you try and what didn't work? The contact page is definitely functional!